# Handling Scope with User Role Constraint - Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

If you try to look at the role name it doesn't really look good. I know this is not the best way to handle such condition. Is there a better way to do it?

```
 public function scopeWishlist( $query ){

     if( Auth::User()->role->name == "admin" || Auth::User()->role->name == "staff"){

        return $query->where('transaction_type', '=', 1);
    }


}
```

Comment: Never compare strings by name @Rbex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much cleaner code

```
public function scopeWishlist($query, $role)
{
  $roles = ['admin', 'staff'];

  return (in_array($role, $roles)) ? $query->where('transaction_type', 1) : $query;
}
```

Then you can do something like

```
Model::where('blahblah', 'blahblah')->wishlist(auth()->user()->role->name)->get();
```

Hope it helps :)